# Creating a constructor for a template class which calls the template initialization within a vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdvector

If I want to create a template class that is able to call the constructor of the template (within the class constructor), is this the way to do it? Or is there a better solution?

```
template<typename T>
class A{
public:
    A(int n): mVector(n) {}                //normal constructor
    A(int n, auto a): mVector(n, T(a)) {}  //constructor with template initialization
private:
    std::vector<T> mVector;
};
```

Also is there a way to extend this for arbitrary amount of Parameters T(a,b,c,...) without having a constructor for every case?

Comment: Be careful with single-argument constructors such as `A(int n)`. Those allow for implicit conversion of `int` to your type, e.g. `void f(A a); f(33);` is valid code. Make them explicit. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Explicit_Constructors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're searching for this:

```
template <typename... Args>
A(int n, Args&&... args) : // First argument should probably be std::size_t
    mVector(n, T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
```

However, you could just take a `const T&` and expect the caller to give you one.